# Export/import opencart

Tags: opencart, импорт, export

Кто то сталкивался с плагином CSV Price Pro import/export? В нем все неплохо, за исключением выгруженного описания товаров. Почему то не выводит все тексты, а только пару тегов да и те без содержания. В чем может быть проблема? Можно ли это исправить? Либо же какой то плагин другой поставить?

Comment: Автор дополнения разве перестал оказывать поддержку своего детища? https://opencartforum.com/profile/10371-costas/

Comment: Сайтом занимался другой человек, и судя по всему плагин не был куплен просто.